# Images not rendered with KnpSnappyBundle/wkhtmltopdf from HTML to PDF

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

Images are not rendered when trying to generate pdf from html, even if the path to the image is right.

In my html template:

```
<img style="width: 100%;" src="{{pathToWeb ~ asset('images/my_image.png') }}">
```

config.yml:

```
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
    globals:
        pathToWeb: "%kernel.project_dir%/web"
```

EDIT: If you downvote the question and find it stupid, at least explain why

---

For some reason, only png images **with at least 1 transparent pixel** are rendered, i have no idea why it works this way but it works. Jpg images won't show up at all.

Comment: The likely reason of your downvote (not from me btw): https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I felt code wasn't needed because this is not a path problem but I edited the question anyway. Thanks

Comment: This is how i solve my problem with the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547506/6883282